# Make a class non-copyable *and* non-movable

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics

Before C++11, I could use this to make a class non-copyable:

```
private:
MyClass(const MyClass&);
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&);
```

With C++11, I can do it like this instead:

```
MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
```

When using the class with the deleted copy and assignment, is there a chance that a default move operator is generated? And the class is not exactly copied, but moved (which is sort of similar) after all?

So, do I have to do this to prevent default move construction and assignmnent:

```
MyClass(MyClass&&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) = delete;
```

... ?

Comment: You don't need it. Personally I put stuff like this into a private base class called `NoCopyOrMove` anyway, so it doesn't clutter my code.

Comment: `MyClass(MyClass&&) = delete;` will implicitly disable the others

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As others already mentioned in the comments, deleted constructors was introduced in C++11. To answer your question, **the following rules hold in general:**

1. The two copy operations are independent. Declaring copy constructor does not prevent compiler to generate copy assignment and vice versa. (Same as in C++98)
2. Move operations are not independent. Declaring either one of them prevents the compiler to generate the other. (Different from copy operations.)
3. **If any of the copy operations is declared, then none of the move operation will be generated.** *(Your case.)*
4. If any of the move operation is declared, then none of the copy operation will be generated. This is the opposite rule of the previous.
5. If a destructor is declared, then none of the move operation will be generated. Copy operations are still generated for reverse compatibility with C++98.
6. Default constructor generated only when no constructor is declared.  (Same as in C++98)

As requested in the comments, here are some sources (C++11 is draft [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)):

- Copy operations: § 12.8.8, § 12.8.19
- Move operations: § 12.8.10, § 12.8.21
- Default constructor: § 12.1.5

Comment: from where you got these facts?

Comment: It was my knowledge :) For your request I extended my answer and added some citations to the C++ standard to support it.

Comment: In which sense is rule4 opposite to rule 3?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: if you declare a copy operation, then the move operations are not generated, and vica versa.

Answer (score 15):

Move constructor/assignment are not generated when you declare a copy constructor.

So

```
MyClass(MyClass&&) = delete;
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) = delete;
```

are not required.

You can still add it to be more explicit.

Comment: Being explicit is good: I always declare all of the operators and selectively `delete` ones I don't need. It makes my intent clear, and just in case there is a compiler bug it should still work the way I expect.

Comment: @Franceso Boi, for a non copyable and non moveable type presumably this sufficies ```MyClass & operator=(MyClass&&) = delete;``` ?