# What are in C++ types that cannot be copied?

Tags: c++, types

In the book "C++ Programming language" by Bjarne Stroustrup when talking about exceptions it says the following:

> An exception is object thrown to represent the occurrance of an error.
>   It can be of any type that can be copied but it is strongly
>   recommended to use only user-defined types specifically defined for
>   that purpose.

Reasoning about it I cannot immediately think of objects that cannot be copied.
What are types that cannot be copied in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173746/how-do-i-make-this-c-object-non-copyable

Comment: Types who's copy constructor has been deleted?

Comment: take iostreams as an example. It just does not make sense to copy an iostream, hence they are built such that you cannot

Comment: @user463035818 the context in which the question is asked doesn't make it a duplicate.

Comment: if you're looking for examples in the standard there's things like `std::unique_ptr`, `std::mutex` and `std::thread` are non-copyable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be copyable an object must define at least one of two possible ways of being copied:

- copy assignment `T& operator=(const T&)`
- copy constructor `T(const T&)`

If no one of these is defined or it has been explicitly deleted (`= delete`) then you can't copy the object.

The requirement arises from the fact that exception handling must be able to copy the exception object itself somewhere for proper management.

Comment: So I can use `delete` to delete the default copy constructor? Syntax is like this: `T(const T&) = delete;`? Do I have also to delete the copy assignment?

Comment: deleted or declared private (the only method in C++98)

Comment: These must be done for both copy assignment and copy constructor or just one? What about C++11 move operators?

Comment: @Clifford: yes, actually making it private doesn't make it uncopyable. It makes the object uncopyable from outside code, but you're still allowed to copy it, eg: https://ideone.com/HpazXw

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: refer to this for general behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096653/make-a-class-non-copyable-and-non-movable, you need to delete both operators to make it uncopyable and being movable is a different concept.

Comment: @Jack : Yes - good point; it is not semantically identical.  However it renders it uncopyable for the purposes of exception handling since it is not copyable by any means the exception handling will be aware of.  I think the Stroustrup text predates C++98 let alone C++11 when deleting member functions was not a thing in C++, so private membership would have been the method at the time.  Often code lasts longer than C++ standards, so I make the point only because the technique may bee seen in maintenance or written by dinosaurs like me who often see little reason to change.

Comment: I kind of take that back - the text in the pre-C++11 third edition does not mention the copyability of an exception object.  So the author will have had member deletion in mind perhaps.